# RecyclerView is empty on "some" devices, but works perfectly on my own device

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an app that uses json data to populate a recyclerview. It works perfectly on my own device.  However, it doesn't work on some devices which even have the same android version with mine.

I found the source of the problem by printing the size of the ArrayList at some stages of the data handling and I am sure nothing is due to network.

The exact problem is that the ArrayList.size() returns 0 on some devices but it doesn't happen on my own device which shows "231" for the size.

The list is defined in the class and initialized in the void.

```
List<Match> liste;
 private void refreshList() {

    String ret = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getString("list");




    try {
       JSONArray bulten = new JSONArray(ret.substring(ret.indexOf("[")));
        if(ret==""){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something is wrong.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        liste = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bulten.length(); i++) {
            String isim,kod,ust,alt,bet;
            bet = bulten.optJSONObject(i).getString("BetTypeId");
            isim = bulten.optJSONObject(i).getString("BetName");
            kod = bulten.optJSONObject(i).getString("Code");
            if(bulten.optJSONObject(i).optJSONArray("Odds25").optJSONObject(0) != null){
            ust = bulten.optJSONObject(i).optJSONArray("Odds25").optJSONObject(0).getString("Value");
            alt = bulten.optJSONObject(i).optJSONArray("Odds25").optJSONObject(1).getString("Value");}
            else{
                ust = "0.00";
                alt= "0.00";

            }
            if(bet == "3"){
            liste.add(new Match(isim,kod,ust,alt));}
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+liste.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
.show(); // The part I show the size of the arraylist is here.

        Collections.sort(liste, new Match.CompId());
       RecyclerView.Adapter adapter1 = new RVAdapter(liste);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter1);




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}








}
```

Here is the Match class:

```
public class Match {
String isim;
String kod;
String ust;
String alt;

Match(String isim, String kod, String ust, String alt) {
    this.isim = isim;
    this.kod = kod;
    this.ust = ust;
    this.alt = alt;
}

public static class CompId implements Comparator<Match> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Match arg0, Match arg1) {
        return Integer.parseInt(arg0.kod) - Integer.parseInt(arg1.kod);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How are you populating the recyclerview? is the data coming from server? Does your device work on wifi and the other on cellular data. is the data fetch taking time? Without code there can be endless possibilities

Comment: Can you share your adapter class? also please specify @kapsym questions.

Comment: @kapsym   I edited the question.

Comment: Then have you updated your recyclerview in the main thread once your data is received?

Comment: @kapsym I think I found the source of the problem, so I am preparing a newer question right now.  Thanks.

Comment: @kapsym I have added the exact spot of the problem in the question, please check it out.

Comment: @ErdemErten this further shows that your list is empty on those devices which means the data has not come from server yet. do you use AsyncTask? Do you call refreshList mehod only when the response is received?

Comment: " I am sure nothing is due to network." because just before the .add() method I checked if the values are right. In addition, the method, as you see, pulls the data from sharedpreferences. @kapsym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this happened but in the line

```
 if(bet == "3"){
        liste.add(new Match(isim,kod,ust,alt));}
    }
```

I was checking if the variable bet is equal to three. It seems that in some devices the string "3" is not read as "3". I changed this line to `bet.contains("3")` 
and it is working right now on those devices.